# Can't rpi-update

Tags: kernel, apt, rpi-update

I can't update the kernel of my pi anymore. When I try I have those errors :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo rpi-update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
This update bumps to rpi-4.4.y linux tree
Be aware there could be compatibility issues with some drivers
Discussion here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=144087
##############################################################
 *** Downloading specific firmware revision (this will take a few minutes)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   168    0   168    0     0    298      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   299
100 51.9M  100 51.9M    0     0   373k      0  0:02:22  0:02:22 --:--:--  662k
 *** Updating firmware
 *** Updating kernel modules
 *** depmod 4.4.43+
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:673 kmod_config_parse: //lib/modules/4.4.43+/modules.softdep line 1: ignoring bad line starting with ELF'
depmod: ERROR: //lib/modules/4.4.43+/modules.order:175 corrupted line misses '\n'
depmod: ../libkmod/libkmod-elf.c:207: elf_get_mem: Assertion `offset < elf->size' failed.
/usr/bin/rpi-update : ligne 74 :  2266 Abandon                 depmod -b "${ROOT_PATH}" -a "${BASEDIR}"
```

I've tried many things (fixing apt-get install, dpkg-reconfigure) but none of this works. I also have issues with apt-get upgrade.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911

Restore the image from your backup.

Comment: Can I update manually then ?

Comment: @Eko `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` will get the latest tested and supported software.